# stage3D independent blend factors for color and alpha channel

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, opengl, air, stage3d

In OpenGL ES it's possible to set different blend functions for color components and the alpha component using http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFuncSeparate.xml

In stage3D I'm aware of Context3D.setBlendFactors(src,dst) but there seems to be no separate control for how the alpha channels shall be combined.

What I'd like to achieve is:

- combine RGB using (ONE, ZERO)
- combine A using (ONE, ONE)

Is this possible in stage3D?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at current list of [available blend factors](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Context3DBlendFactor.html), it is not possible. You should fill a feature request at Adobe JIRA.